# Invalid Cast Exception when during SQL querying

Tags: c#, sql

There is an exception message when I run the website

> " Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type
>   'System.String'."

emereging from the 'value' part of `'return (string)c.Parameters["@vat"].Value;`' in the below code. I checked the stored procedure to see if it executes the query, it does and its output is a string as well. Can Anyone help..??

```
namespace CamOnlineAccess
{
  public class Utilities
  {
    public SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection();
        c.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CamOnlineConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        return c;
    }

    public SqlCommand GetCommandSP(string SPName)
    {
        SqlCommand c = new SqlCommand();
        c.Connection = GetConnection();
        c.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        c.CommandText = SPName;
        c.CommandTimeout = 150;

        return c;
    }
  }
}

public string ViewUserVat(string code)
{
    CamOnlineAccess.Utilities u = new CamOnlineAccess.Utilities();
    SqlCommand c = u.GetCommandSP("dbo.ViewUserVat");

    c.Parameters.AddRange(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter[] {
        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@code", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50),
            new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@vat",SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output, false, ((byte)(0)), ((byte)(0)), "", System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, null)});
    c.Parameters["@code"].Value = code;
    c.Connection.Open();
    c.ExecuteScalar();//because we have output parameters
    c.Connection.Close();

    return (string)c.Parameters["@vat"].Value;
 }
```

STRORED PROCEDURE

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ViewUserVat] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@code varchar,
@vat varchar(50) output

    AS
SELECT top 1 @vat=vattable from dbo.portfolio 
where owner=@code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return directly the parameter value assuming that your stored procedure will always find a record for the parameter `@code` and the column `vattable` is never null.

This is not the case as you can see, and you get a `DBNull` in return.
You should change your code to

```
 return (c.Parameters["@vat"].Value == DBNull.Value ? 
              null : 
              c.Parameters["@vat"].Value.ToString());
```

Of course, assuming a `null` is an allowed/expected return value for the rest of your code.
Otherwise, you can replace the `null` with another acceptable value (eg string.Empty)

Comment: `null` would be a more appropriate choice than `string.Empty`, IMO. `""` != `null`

Comment: I consider is correct to return `null` instead of empty string.

Comment: OK, just assuming, changed the answer to reflect the @MarcGravell notes

Comment: Also Is there a way for me to know what is being returned as vat during the run..??

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please, when the site allows, remember to accept the answer if this has been useful to you.

Comment: You are returning just one record (TOP 1) so, this in not a problem you could resolve here, but in the code calling ViewUserVat.

Comment: I have two instances in my login page depending on what is returned as vat, when I execute the stored procedure the result is 'INTERNAL', but the the condition on 'else' gets executed instead of 'INTERNAL'

Comment: I think you need to post another question with more details about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
return String.Format("{0}",c.Parameters["@vat"].Value);
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
return (string)(c.Parameters["@vat"].Value == DBNull.Value
           ? null
           : c.Parameters["@vat"].Value);
```